# Any way to replace visual studio's usage of msbuild and still get error reporting in the IDE?

Tags: ide, msbuild, build-automation

Any way to replace visual studio's usage of msbuild and still get error reporting in the IDE?  I think I might want to compile in VS with NAnt or Rake or PowerShell, or something that is just as smart but uses a scripting language instead of XML.  My build is fairly straight forward -- find all the .cs and compile them and put the dll in a Debug/ or Release/ etc.

I'd like to add a number of other steps that just seem easier from the command line:

- Like hit the server to prime certain caches.
- Compile with Closure
- Minify CSS
- Generate some metrics after build (in a certain config)
- Run NUnit (or custom) testing framework and send an email
- etc....

However, I'd still like to get the "error on line" feed back inside of the IDE.  Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write some extension for Visual Studio (Macro, AddIn, Package, etc.) that can augment Visual Studio to let other build tools run. The simplest form is probably just using "Tools\External Tools.." and add your Build Tool there. As long as you format your "build messages" as [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxkt8b26.aspx), the should show up the output window as if they were generated by MSBuild.

However, I don't think it is possible (nor desirable, BTW) to completely replace MSBuild in Visual Studio.

Visual Studio not just executes `MSBuild.exe` and parses it's output. The integration is [very tight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171468.aspx) and a lot of GUI aspects rely directly on the content of the MSBuild file. 
For example, when you change some project properties in the Visual Studio UI, the changes are (eventually) written to the MSBuild file of the project.

Also, there are some performance improvements, for example Visual Studio "replaces", so to say, the call of `csc.exe` (the C# compiler) from an MSBuild file by using an in-process compiler, which safes some compile time, because less external processes need to be launched (also described in the [above mentioned document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171468.aspx))

While all this, from a architectural point of view, is quit likely wrapped and encapsulated by some "interfaces" inside Visual Studio, I haven't yet found a way to have those "interfaces" implement something else that, for example, uses NAnt behind.

Anyway, I think even if technically possible, it would not be technically feasible.

Comment: nice example of this with screen shots http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HackParallelMSBuildsFromWithinTheVisualStudioIDE.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For rake, check out [Rake Runner](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/551978a5-68e3-452b-9067-22ef237ce929) extension. You can run the rake tasks from the solution explorer and check the errors and other output in the `Output` pane. I have little experience developing vs packages so if anyone want to help, the project is open sourced [here](https://github.com/shawnmclean/Rake-Runner).